# Jest refusing to parse JSX despite tsconfig including `jsx` option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test react components written in typescript with Jest, but when I run the tests I get this error:

```
Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.
```

This project needs multiple tsconfig files (one for a node server and another for the client source), so the project is structured like this:

```
/root
  package.json
  jest.config.js
  /src
    tsconfig.json
  /server
    tsconfig.json
```

I'm currently only trying to run tests in the `src` directory. I think the issue is that ts-jest isn't loading the correct tsconfig file, but after browsing their docs, issues, and asking on the slack channel, I can't find any way to either pass the `--jsx` flag to ts-jest or to specify the tsconfig to use.

Here are the contents of my config files:

**/root/jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  roots: [
    '<rootDir>/src',
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testRegex: '/__tests__/.*\\.test\\.tsx?$',
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'ts',
    'tsx',
    'js',
    'jsx',
    'json',
    'node',
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['jest-enzyme'],
  testEnvironment: 'enzyme',
};
```

**/root/src/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-styled-plugin"
      }
    ],
    "target": "es2018",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "../dist/src",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": ["./types", "../node_modules/@types"]
  }
}
```

And my relevant dependencies in `package.json`

```
"@types/jest": "^24.0.10",
"@types/enzyme": "^3.9.0",
"enzyme": "^3.9.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.10.0",
"jest": "^24.3.1",
"jest-environment-enzyme": "^7.0.2",
"jest-enzyme": "^7.0.2",
"ts-jest": "^24.0.0",
"ts-node": "^8.0.2",
"typescript": "^3.3.3",
"typescript-styled-plugin": "^0.13.0"
```

And the test that is failing (located at `/root/src/pages/__tests__/index.test.tsx`)

```
import React from 'react';
import IndexPage from '../index';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('pages/index', () => {
  test('Should render without error', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<IndexPage/>);
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

I've got it working in the meantime by just moving `root/src/tsconfig.json` to `root/tsconfig.json`. This won't work if I ever want to add tests to the server, but I'll use it until something better comes up.

Comment: ts-jest by default look for `<root>/tsconfig.json`. If you want it to find the file in a different location, use `global/ts-jest/tsconfig` setting

Comment: @unional Thanks. After a bit more searching, I found that in the docs (guess I didn't look hard enough before posting this). If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ts-jest` will look for `<roodDir>/tsconfig.json` by default.

If you want to specify a specific config file, use the `global/ts-jest/tsconfig` option:

```
//  package.json/jest or jest.config.json
{
  "globals": {
    "ts-jest": {
      "tsConfig": "<your tsconfig.json file path>"
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/#options

Comment: edited to match docs. had to add extra characters to exceed edit threshold

Comment: Apparently deprecated now. Old: `tsConfig` New: `tsconfig`.